# Elasticsearch: Sort by field of nested object of child document

Tags: elasticsearch

Using elasticsearch 7.10.

Say I have series with episodes with publications. Episodes are broadcast on different channels. So each episode has more than one publication with fields `startTime`, `endTime` and `channel`.

- `series` is the top of the hierarchy
- `episode` is a child of series
- `publications` are nested objects inside episode.

I want to list the latest series broadcast on channel X, sorted by the startTime of the publication with channel X.

So I need to sort series by the startTime value of a specific publication of each episode belongin to the series.

I was looking at function_score query but can't find a scoring function that does what I want. Is it even possible? The `field_value_factor` filter comes closest but it doesn't allow for choosing which nested object to use.